# Getting an error for the parentheses after row_number for postgresql-12

Tags: postgresql-12

I am attempting to use window ranking to get the three orders
with the highest profit per each product_id using order_id as the tiebreaker from sales table.  The code I've written is:

```
with C as
(
select product_id, order_id, profit
row_number() over(partition by product_id order by profit desc, order_id) as rownum
from sales
)
select *
from C
where rownum <= 3
order by product_id, rownum;
```

I get the error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
> LINE 4: row_number() over
> SQL state: 42601
> ```

Can someone help with the error in my syntax?

Comment: Missing comma after profit

Comment: Yup.  Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0):

(Repeating my comment so this post has an answer)

The query is missing a comma after the profit column. The compiler assumed you wanted to display profit as "row_number" then saw the () which caused the error.

```
with C as (
select product_id, order_id, profit,       <-- Needed comma here
row_number() over(partition by product_id
order by profit desc, order_id) as rownum
from sales
...........
```